# Is there a way to get configurations from git repository and save them to zookeeper?

Tags: java, spring, git, apache-zookeeper

I need a java application that will monitor git repository and whenever there is a change it will save it to zookeeper. I need to distribute my configurations from git repository to zookeeper. Does someone know is there a ready solutions to that? Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to do what you said. 
Because I have used git as a configuration center. 
I have also used zk as a configuration center. 
So we can read and write configuration from git, and also read and write configuration from zk. 
What you have to do is read the configuration from git, and then write the configuration to zk

Comment: Many people use hosting services like Github, Gitlab, Gerrit, and etc. These hosting services have hooks that monitor the events in the repository. They allow users to write scripts to do something when an event happens. Besides hooks, Jenkins is another solution. It has some plugins to monitor the events and then trigger a job. Users can write scripts or use other plugins to do something in the job.